# How to set property of 'X-IW-SESSION' in Flutter

Tags: authentication, flutter, authorization

I am converting my employer's current android app to flutter. One of the difficulties I have been facing recently is how I post data to the server with json.

For some data transactions, the server requires the 'X-IW-SESSION', which is set as follows in the original app:

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("X-IW-SESSION", session);
```

I've tried using the following properties, but I am unable to get the result I need.

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: session,
    };
```

I checked this over flutter's official documentation. I couldn't find the name 'x-iw-session' but saw something similar = `HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader`.

In the old android app, the 'x-iw-session' helps the user to login using a session (String) which is stored in the shared preferences.
In the flutter app, I have access to the same session (String), but I am lost as to how should I use the same to login into the server.

Currently, this is what my server sends as response for failure:

```
{success: false, message: Please Login..You dont have permission}
```

Please do tell, If I need to show some specific code.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this would work.

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
      ”X-IW-SESSION”: session,
    };
```

If so, check for a declaration in HttpHeaders.

Comment: That did not work. I have tried almost all of the headers that could have to do anything with authorization/login. But for some reason, nothing has been working so far.